# How to fit a linear part of a load vs. displacement curve?

Tags: python

I need help with fitting my load vs. displacement curve in python. I plotted a curve so far but I have no idea how to make a linear fit to calculate the yield strength and Young modulus of my material. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!
Below is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.genfromtxt('test.txt', delimiter= None, skip_header=2)
x1=data[:,0]
y1=data[:,1]
plt.plot(x1,y1, 'b', label='')
plt.xlabel('Displacement [mm]')
plt.ylabel('Load [kN]')
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Load vs Actuator Displacement')
plt.savefig('load_displacement_curve.png', dpi=300)
```

Comment: You can use [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy.stats.linregress) for example. I don't know what your data looks like, but you'll want to make sure you only fit the elastic portion of your curve, because once the material yields the plastic behavior is nonlinear so you don't want to try to get a Young's modulus from that portion of the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use this library :
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/

An example with Ordinary Least Squares
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py

I give you an example that you can find in their web:

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
>>> reg.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
LinearRegression()
>>> reg.coef_
array([0.5, 0.5])
```